# Swagger issue: Only one .json file is generator for the default version

Tags: .net-core, swagger, versioning, webapi

I just have tested a great article about WebApi versioning from this website:
https://www.meziantou.net/versioning-an-asp-net-core-api.htm

It works partially: It should generate two Swagger documents, one for each version.
But it actually only generates a document for the given defaultApiVersion. In my example this was set to 2.0. The older WebApi controllers marked with 1.0 do not result into a document. And based on the 2 commands below, I had also expected that the WebApi controllers without any version attribute should be visible in the 2.0 documentation. (Which doesn't happen either).

options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2, 0);
options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;

Can someone give a suggestion about what is happening here?

Kind regards, Mark.